# How does Popen handle memory?

Tags: python, memory-management, subprocess, out-of-memory, popen

I have inherited code that eventually dies because it can no longer allocate memory.

I am trying to identify what is building up memory usage, and so my initial thought is that the code calls popen hundreds of thousands of times during tests. It does not call communicate, kill, or terminate on those subprocesses, but in theory, it reaches the end of file and should terminate those, correct?

I tried to create a test as follows:

FILE 1: This file will run and "accumulate" subprocesses via `Popen`:

```
import subprocess
import time

while True:
    pinger = subprocess.Popen('ipconfig')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pinger.terminate() #I test with this line and without this line to see if behavior changes.  It does not change in a noticeable way.
```

FILE 2: This file starts running **before** file 1, such that it allows me to capture the file 1 python process and view its memory usage over time (updating every 3 seconds)

```
import psutil
import time
import subprocess

list_of_procs = []
counter = 0
new_procs = []
while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            processName = proc.name()
            processID = proc.pid
            if counter>0:
                if (processID not in list_of_procs) and (processName.lower() == 'python.exe'):
                    print(f'new process found: ID {processID}')
                    print(f'Process is named {processName}')
                    new_procs.append(processID)
            if processID not in list_of_procs:
                list_of_procs.append(processID)
            #print(processName , ' ::: ', processID)
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
    if len(new_procs)>0:
        for item in new_procs:
            print(psutil.Process(item).as_dict(attrs=['pid','name','memory_full_info']))
    counter=counter+1
```

Right now, I do see the memory accumulate very slowly.  I'm primarily focused on the "uss" attribute from `memory_full_info`.

That attribute increases, but it does not increase with every popen, it may only increase every 15 seconds or so, despite the python process I'm tracking kicking off new `Popen` instances every .1 second.

If someone could help me make sense of this, develop a different more meaningful test, or simply understands `Popen`and the `subprocess` module better, please advise.

Comment: You need to reap the terminated processes by calling `wait` on them. IDK if that's the source of the leak though.

Comment: Im digging through the code for any dictionaries or lists or dataframes etc that are being appended to constantly but old data not dropped from them.  Could you elaborate on what wait does?  Im more so looking for data on whether or not I need to include a terminate or kill command in my loops, but the test was non conclusive